# How to convert Khan academy code to p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using the https://editor.p5js.org/Josef37/sketches/RGDv9lHkK for convert to p5.js and I'm still don't know how to convert 100% correct, the **picture won't show up when i convert myCode** from the **khanAcademy Original code** to p5.js and can you also help me put the **sound clack.wave when Block fall down** in my code as well?

**myCode**

```js
function preload() {
  blockImg = loadImage('block.png');
}

var Block = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = loadImage("block.png");
    this.sticks = 0;
};


  
  
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

Block.prototype.draw = function() {
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};
  
Block.prototype.hop = function() {
    this.img = getImage("block.png");
    this.y -= -44;
};

Block.prototype.fall = function() {
    this.img = getImage("block.png");
    this.y += 5;
};
}



function draw() {
  background(200);

var block = new Block(10, 300);
block.draw();

}
```

**I'm using P5.js on this website** >https://editor.p5js.org/Josef37/sketches/RGDv9lHkK
<

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/side-scroller/a/beaver-character
**Original Code from KhanAcademy**

```js
var Beaver = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Happy");
    this.sticks = 0;
};

Beaver.prototype.draw = function() {
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 40, 40);
};

Beaver.prototype.hop = function() {
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Jumping");
    this.y -= -44;
};

Beaver.prototype.fall = function() {
    this.img = getImage("creatures/Hopper-Happy");
    this.y += 5;//Down Gavity
};


var beaver = new Beaver(10, 300);
beaver.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to call the asynchronous `loadImage()` function within your constructor, which means the image will not be able to load before you attempt to draw the Block with `.draw()`.

You already do check to make sure it has finished loading by putting an initial `loadImage()` call in your `preload()`, so the image will be loaded by the time your `setup()` and `draw()` functions run. This means you can just set the image to the preloaded one within your constructor:

```
var Block = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.img = blockImg;
  this.sticks = 0;
};
```

Also, make sure to switch all your `getImage()`s to preloaded `loadImage()`s and their returned Objects, as `getImage()` does not exist within p5.js and using just `loadImage()` may give you the same problem you're having here.